# How to unserialize data in admin form

Tags: magento2, admin

I need to unserialize data before displaying in admin

> [product_id] => a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"1";}

My admin fieldset code

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'product_id',
            'textarea',
            ['name' => 'product_id', 'label' => __('Product Id'), 'title' => __('Product Id')]
        );
```

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310142/magento2-serialize-data-before-displaying-in-grid/310941#310941

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $json
    ) {
        $this->json = $json;
    }

 public function yourFunction()
 {
   $jsonDecode = $this->json->unserialize($result);

   $json = $this->json->serialize($jsonDecode);

 }
```