# Magento2 serialize data before displaying in grid

Tags: magento2

How can i unserialize data before displaying in Grid

```
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('inquiryGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('inquiry_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    public function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'inquiry_id',
            [
            'header'    => __('ID'),
            'index'     => 'inquiry_id',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn('product_id', ['header' => __('Product Id'), 'index' => 'product_id']);
        $this->addColumn('product_name', ['header' => __('Product Name'), 'index' => 'product_name']);
        $this->addColumn('product_sku', ['header' => __('Product SKU'), 'index' => 'product_sku']);
        $this->addColumn('first_name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'first_name']);
        // $this->addColumn('last_name', ['header' => __('Last Name'), 'index' => 'last_name']);
        $this->addColumn('email', ['header' => __('Email'), 'index' => 'email']);
        $this->addColumn('telephone', ['header' => __('Phone Number'), 'index' => 'telephone']);

        // $this->addColumn(
        //     'published_at',
        //     [
        //         'header' => __('Published On'),
        //         'index' => 'published_at',
        //         'type' => 'date',
        //         'header_css_class' => 'col-date',
        //         'column_css_class' => 'col-date'
        //     ]
        // );

        // $this->addColumn(
        //     'created_at',
        //     [
        //         'header' => __('Created'),
        //         'index' => 'created_at',
        //         'type' => 'datetime',
        //         'header_css_class' => 'col-date',
        //         'column_css_class' => 'col-date'
        //     ]
        // );

        $this->addColumn(
            'action',
            [
                'header' => __('View Details'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('View Details'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                        ],
                        'field' => 'inquiry_id'
                    ]
                ],
                'sortable' => false,
                'filter' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', ['inquiry_id' => $row->getId()]);
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any code & got any error ?

Comment: Check this -https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-serialize-value-in-array-format-using-magento-2/